# Get-ADUser with multiple filters & variables

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get AD users into a variable using multiple filters. However one of the filters has variables in it & I can't get it to work... I have searched for similar issues & tried applying those but nothing seems to work.

```
$FilterBase = "department"
$Filter = "IT"

$ADusers = Get-ADUser -ResultSetSize $null -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -Properties * -Filter {(Enabled -eq $True) -and ($FilterBase -like $Filter) -and (cn -notlike ""SMB_*"")} |
            Select-Object distinguishedName |
            Sort-Object distinguishedName
```

I'm trying to fill `$ADusers` with all enabled users whose commonname doesn't start with "SMB_" (don't ask) & where the department is IT. I used `-like` to prevent issues if the values in AD would have different casings (uppercase, lowercase, mixed case, ...).

The reason that I'm using variables for this is because in the end the script will be dynamic. At some point `$FilterBase` is going to be "company" instead of "department" and `$Filter` is going to be "HR" instead of "IT" etc...

But I just can't seem to get it to work:

```
 Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: '(Enabled -eq $True) -and ($FilterBase -like $Filter) -and (cn -notlike ""SMB_*"")' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '74'.
    At line:4 char:12
```

I have tried using quotes around the variables like "`$Filter`", "`$($Filter)`", ' `$Filter` ' but alas. And I know it's not best practice to use variables in Filter but I can't think of any other way to accomplish this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: since `-Filter` uses a STRING, not a scriptblock [even tho many samples show a scriptblock], you need to use a string - and PoSh requires that the OUTER quotes be double quotes if you want any $Var in the string to be expanded.

Comment: I changed it to `-Filter "(Enabled -eq $True) -and ($FilterBase -like ""$Filter"") -and (cn -notlike ""SMB_*"")"` but I still get a syntax error. Even though the proper values are being shown for the variables in the error now: `Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: '(Enabled -eq True) -and (department -eq "IT") -and (cn -notlike "SMB_*")' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '14'.`

Comment: this is how to do a filter string for the AD cmdlets >>> `"(Enabled -eq $True) -and ($FilterBase -like '$Filter') -and (cn -notlike 'SMB_*')"` <<< ///// what i don't know is if `-notlike` is valid. nor do i know if you can use a $Var for the keyword in a filter. [*blush*] also, you are using `-like` without any wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

the error has the key to the answer. I'm sure I'll find this again and use it myself because I look this up every year or so...

Error parsing query: '(Enabled -eq $True)...'

In this case the filter needs a simple string 'True' which the variable $True does equal.

Two options will work, either

Enabled -eq 'True'
or
Enabled -eq '$True'

but

Enabled -eq $True

will not.

This should work

- Replaced the braces with double quotes so inside them the variables still parse
- Put single quotes around all strings and variables that resolve into strings
- '$True'
- '$Filter'
- 'SMB_*'

```
$FilterBase = "department"
$Filter = "IT"

$ADusers = Get-ADUser -ResultSetSize $null -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -Properties CN -Filter "(Enabled -eq '$True') -and ('$FilterBase' -like '$Filter') -and (CN -notlike 'SMB_*')" |
            Select-Object distinguishedName |
            Sort-Object distinguishedName
```

Important to note the above syntax highlighting will make the sample above look wrong because it misses the tokens like $FilterBase and $Filter when there are inside single quotes *inside* double quotes. Remember that single quotes are just apostrophes when inside double quotes, therefore the tokens should be colored differently and not look like strings.

```
> "('$FilterBase' -like '$Filter')"
('department' -like 'IT')
```

Paste a sample like above and see what it resolves to - best way to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

its just simply syntax error.

```
$enabled = 'Enabled'
$EnabledTrueOrFalse = $true
$SN = 'Surname'
$surname = "Doe"
$OU = "OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com"

Get-ADuser -filter{$enabled -eq $EnabledTrueOrFalse -and $SN -eq $surname} -SearchBase $OU -Properties * | Select-Object distinguishedName | Sort-Object distinguishedName
```

read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)

Comment: This only works as long as I don't use variables. `'(Enabled -eq $True) -and (cn -notlike "SMB_*")'` works but `'(Enabled -eq $True) -and ($FilterBase -eq ""$Filter"") -and (cn -notlike "SMB_*")'` does not...

Comment: Edited in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips guys. I couldn't get it to work with multiple filters so I moved some filters to the where clause.

My current (working) code is now:

```
$FilterBase = "department"
$Filter = "IT"

$ADusers = Get-ADUser -ResultSetSize $null -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -Properties * -Filter "$FilterBase -like `"$Filter`"" |
Where {$_.Enabled -eq $True -and $_.CN -notlike "SMB_*"} |
Select-Object distinguishedName |
Sort-Object distinguishedName
```